# Converting balanced audio to RCA/phono audio - mixer needed?

Tags: audio

I want to send balanced audio from one room to another in my home. The audio will originate from a Soundcraft Spirit Folio 12/2 mixing console desk.

I'm assuming that the mix left/right and/or aux 1/2 outputs from this desk are balanced - but I'm not sure (so I've asked a seperate question above this here: [What Soundcraft Spirit Folio 12/2 mixing desk/console outputs are balanced?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/46106/what-soundcraft-spirit-folio-12-2-mixing-desk-console-outputs-are-balanced) ).

If they're not, I would connect them to a Behringer Ultra DI DI20 box and attach 2 balanced cables I have already laid to it. I have done some tests already that indicate that the signal sent is good quality with very low noise.

At the other end, I want to feed the audio input as RCA phono stereo pair into a Technics HiFi amplifier. For this:

- can I use cables that 'convert' balanced to unbalanced? (e.g. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pseudo-Balanced-Phono-Damme-Starquad/dp/B01MRZ21TO or https://www.canford.co.uk/CANFORD-BALANCED-TO-UNBALANCED-CONVERTERS )
- Can I assume that such cables are bidirectional in that if they are
  listed as unbalanced to balanced, they will also do it the other way
  around?
- Or should I consider a 2nd small mixing desk to do the conversion. I haven't found one that provides unbalanced output. For example https://www.soundcraft.com/en/products/notepad-5 - nice mixer, <strike>but balanced only outputs it seems</strike> **Correction:** They also have unbalanced output in the form of a stereo 6.35mm jack output.

I guess that converting balanced to unbalanced might be simple enough to implement in a cable. After all, the sound ultimately ends up that way by summing the +ve and -ve (mirror images of the sound), to cancel out the same noise signal by inverting one of the signals before summing.

Thanks for reading and any input appreciated.

Comment: "Pseudo-Balanced" I nearly fell off my chair laughing. That is marketing-speak gone mad. On the other hand, the Canford stuff looks good. Overall, that's a lot of money to be spending pushing a stereo signal round a house. How far are you pushing it? If it's less than 50m, I'd see how you get away with unbalanced right through. [50 is almost a bridge too far, but it may depend on how electrically noisy your environment is, 25 should be easy.]

Comment: +1 thank you @Tetsujin The 25m cable is for connecting my home office (2nd bedroom) to my lounge/kitchen. Initially, I did use a 25m cable consisting of 2 unbalanced leads for left and right phono at each end. The result here was very noticable hum.

Comment: I also already had 2 25m balanced XLR cables which I ran the same route. I plugged the audio source in my home office into a Behringer Ultra DI DI20 and connected the 2 balanced XLRs to it. At the other end, in my lounge, I plugged the cable XLR plugs into my Spirit Folio 12/2. Power for the Behringer Ultra DI DI20 provided by the Spirit Folio's phantom power. Then, unbalanced 6.35cm jacks with phono ends were used to connect the Spirit to my Technics amplifier. Result: very clean audio signal. Hum very faintly noticeable when Technics amplifier turned up to full volume and some hiss.

Comment: Conclusion: the balanced cables making a huge difference. Their route includes running under my kitchen units (fridge/freezer, cooker, sink, dishwasher) as my flat's lounge is really a lounge/kitched combined room.

Comment: As regards off-topic designation of this question by @Rory Alsop ♦, I can appreciate the thinking. However, although my problem is in a home setting, it does involve the application of professional technologies such as balanced XLR and products from professional audio product makers (Soundcraft and Behringer). Also, the setup in my home office is for a small home studio. Thank you for your considerations and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use cables that 'convert' balanced to unbalanced?

Yes, depending on your environment. As Mark said, the entire length of the cable is unbalanced, so you lose the noise rejection that a balanced link would give you. If you're not running power cables etc. near your audio lines you can get away with an unbalanced connection. I wouldn't rely on this in a setting where you regularly have to move your system (PA hire for example).

> Can I assume that such cables are bidirectional in that if they are listed as unbalanced to balanced, they will also do it the other way around?

No. Those cables just make your link unbalanced in both directions.

The Canford converters you linked to, are bidirectional. They use a different method (a transformer) that actually converts the signal. This is basically a passive DI. 
If you place this converter at the end of a balanced link, you preserve the balanced link and its noise rejection.

As an alternative, an active DI would also work, but those have to be powered. They're usually built to take phantom power or a battery, I haven't seen DIs that can be mains-powered.

Note that in the same form factor as the Canford converter, you can also get converters that just connect pin 1 to 3 (as in the "pseudo-balanced" cable you linked to).

Comment: +1 upvote and accepted answer for providing requested advice on the products in the question and for indicating a solution - the Canford converter. Thank you!

Comment: On the basis of this answer and that it would appear that the Spirit Folio outputs I am using aren't balanced, then my perhaps final solution would be to have the Mix L+R or Aux 1/2 outputs (Which I assume to be unbalanced) going into a Behringer Ultra DI DI120 and the XLR cables coming out from that to go to the lounge. As the other end, in the lounge, I would use the Canford item to convert from balanced to unbalanced for the Technics amplifier, based on the Canford's technical spec that it is faithful to the balancing and doesn't lose it as you say.

Comment: The Behringer Ultra DI DI120 will need powering - as because the Canford converter at the other end is passive there is no power supply provided. The 2 options are: Phantom power from a mixer or a 9v battery.

Comment: But because there is no phantom power available as said. The 9v battery is the option. I'd rather not rely on a battery that will eventually go flat so would be looking at getting a USB power to 9v battery adapter to provide power, for example: https://hobbyking.com/en_us/znter-9v-400mah-usb-rechargeable-li-po-battery.html?___store=en_us - however, I may have to be aware of potential ground loop issues owing to the power source coming from a supply which is ultimately from the same mains power, which would scupper the whole implementation!

Comment: The canford connectors look like they do the job but are very pricey at around 100 pounds for each channel - total 200 pounds. Instead I'm inclined to get the https://www.soundcraft.com/en/products/notepad-5 or https://www.soundcraft.com/en/products/notepad-8fx which have a stereo headphone output as well as their balanced master outputs. These are around half the price of paying for 2 canford converters and they give versatility for other applications as well. I've already tested a similar setup with my existing Spirit Folio 12/2. Thanks again.

Comment: yes, good passive DIs can be expensive, and cheap ones degrade the signal.

Comment: +1 Thank you Hobbes. Certainly, I think that the Canford passive converter has very relevant applications: for example in confined spaces, unattended, or quality reliability. The Soundcraft Notepad that I am probably going to get suits me better for my case and I expect it to be of the usual Soundcraft high quality and reliability. I've owned the Spirit Folio 12/2 since 1993 and it's still going strong, no issues.

Comment: But a mixing console to do the balanced to unbalanced conversion might not suit some applications where they don't want something that could get tampered with, accidentally adjusted, or lacking the space as well as another thing to setup. I can imagine the Canford item does what it does and does it very well. Thank you again!

Comment: The Canford item has another feature: unlike an active DI, it provides electrical isolation. This is useful if you have interference due to ground loops.

Comment: +1 thank you again Hobbes. There is another cheaper passive transformer DI box, the ART DTI which stereo/2 channel but is half the price of one Canford mono DI. The ART DTI also has phono/rca/cinch (unbalanced) inputs and outputs. https://artproaudio.com/product/dti-dual-transformer-isolator/  The spec sheet includes a schematic that confirms transformers inside (true galvanic isolation) https://artproaudio.com/framework/uploads/2018/06/ss_dti.pdf The spec states a wide flat/even frequency response and many amazon and google reviewers rate it positively.

Comment: Sound on Sound also suggest the Art DTI for converting phantom powered balanced audio outputs to non-phantom powered balanced to avoid damage to equipment.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the Art DTI, Hobbes?

Comment: I've never used it. The specs are good enough that I'd be tempted to try one the next time I go shopping for DIs.

Answer (score 1):

Once you unbalance one end of an XLR cable (by linking pins 1 and 3) the *entire* length of the cable is unbalanced. You will need two devices at each end to send the signal balanced - a DI at one end and a balancing transformer or similar at the other end.

Comment: +1 For advice related to that requested in the question, as well as to corroborate the answer given by @Hobbes. Thank you!